# Two group-bys in a query, one without an aggregate function.

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

```
SELECT events.id, events.name, events.code, event_statuses.name as event_status_name
 , regions.name as event_region_name, event_locations.name as event_location_name
 , events.date_1, events.date_2
 , count(r.id) as regs 
FROM events 
 INNER JOIN event_locations ON event_locations.id = events.event_location_id 
 INNER JOIN event_statuses ON event_statuses.id = events.event_status_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN regions ON regions.id = events.region_id 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN registrations as r ON events.id = r.event_id and r.registration_status_id = 4 
WHERE 1 GROUP BY events.id ORDER BY date_1 DESC LIMIT 0, 50
```

As you can see, my query has an aggregate function and which it performs on registrations grouped by events.

However, I want to have another `GROUP BY` in this query, this one without any other aggregate function. The point here is that I want the events list to be grouped by Regions - now matter what they're sorted by. If they're sorted by `regs` -- I would all events from Boston to be shown clumped together, and then sorted by regs. Hence needing another Group By. This is what I came up with, but this isn't working either:

```
SELECT events.id, events.name, events.code, event_statuses.name as event_status_name
 ,regions.name as event_region_name, event_locations.name as event_location_name
 , events.date_1, events.date_2, r.regs
 FROM events 
 INNER JOIN event_locations ON event_locations.id = events.event_location_id 
 INNER JOIN event_statuses ON event_statuses.id = events.event_status_id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN regions ON regions.id = events.region_id 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (Select event_id, count(id) as regs 
        from registrations where registration_status_id = 4 
        group by event_id) r on events.id = r.event_id
 WHERE 1 GROUP BY events.region_id, events.id ORDER BY date_1 DESC LIMIT 0, 50
```

I still can't group them by region together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the events list to be grouped by Regions - now matter what they're sorted by. If they're sorted by regs -- I would all events from Boston to be shown clumped together, and then sorted by regs.

You want ORDER BY for this, not GROUP BY. You can add the field you want to be "clumped together" before all the other fields in your ORDER BY clause.

```
ORDER BY region_id, regs
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version

```
SELECT
  events.id,
  events.region_id,
  events.name,
  events.code,
  event_statuses.name  as event_status_name,
  regions.name         as event_region_name,
  event_locations.name as event_location_name,
  events.date_1,
  events.date_2,
  r.regs
FROM events
  INNER JOIN event_locations
    ON event_locations.id = events.event_location_id
  INNER JOIN event_statuses
    ON event_statuses.id = events.event_status_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN regions
    ON regions.id = events.region_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (Select
                 event_id,
                 count(id)             as regs
               from registrations
               where registration_status_id = 4
               group by event_id) r
    on events.id = r.event_id
WHERE 1
GROUP BY events.region_id, events.id
ORDER BY date_1 DESC
LIMIT 0, 50
```

Try this i have only selected the column events.region_id

Comment: i have added events.region_id which will be selected then will be used for group by

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "clumped together" then it sound like you want to use and aggregate for the regs.

```
SELECT 
  events.id, 
  events.name, 
  events.code, 
  event_statuses.name as event_status_name,
  regions.name as event_region_name, 
  event_locations.name as event_location_name, 
  events.date_1, 
  events.date_2, 
  SUM(r.regs) AS regs
....
GROUP BY events.region_id, events.id ORDER BY date_1 DESC LIMIT 0, 50
```

Comment: I am sorry for using bad english Arion, I just meant Grouped.